# Possible to hide Site Actions menu content by permission level through CustomSiteAction.xml in Sharepoint 2013?

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-designer, sharepoint-foundation

Is this possible? I am trying to limit view of the "View All Site Content" menu to administrators only, and I am able to to it on individual sites by editing the seattle.master page in each directory. However, when I go to the main team site, the seattle.master file is the different content type "ASP NET Master Page" as opposed to "Master Page" and does not have the "TemplateMenuItem" to edit the "PermissionString" on. This is a non-publishing site on Sharepoint 2013, hosted.

Can I edit the main team sites /masterpage/Editing Menu/CustomSiteAction.xml to accomplish this? Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: @tola Let me clarify, I'm trying to hide the "Site Contents" button on the Site Actions menu for users who do not have administrator access. The master page associated with the main team site does not contain the controls to trim, and I'm not sure why. I can trim them easily on "normal" master pages that my subsites use, but not the seattle.master file that the main team site uses. This is why I was wondering if I could trim the menu with the CustomSiteActions.xml file, as I can only find documentation on hiding them from there. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

This should be done by using Site permission group. for Ex. I grand administrator user to Site Owner, and other user to site visitor or to other group and depending on permission level.